# not getting sort output in awk

Tags: awk

I am using book "The AWK programming langauge" by Aho ,Kernighan ..
On page 20 they have given a program which doesn't work on my system.

emp.data is

```
Beth 4.00 0
Dan 3.75  0
Kathy 4.00 10
Mark 5.00 20
Mary  5.50 22
Susie  4.25 18
```

program they have given is

```
awk '{ printf("%6.2f  %s\n" , $2*$3, $0) }' emp.data | sort
```

and the output they have given is

[image]

But my output is

```
0.00  Beth 4.00 0
  0.00  Dan 3.75  0
100.00  Mark 5.00 20
121.00  Mary  5.50 22
 40.00  Kathy 4.00 10
 76.50  Susie  4.25 18
```

so whats  happening ?

Comment: Throw that book out as it's very old and not very good. Get Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition By Arnold Robbins instead. Their printf syntax above is wrong, for example. Having said that, there's something very wrong with your version of "awk" if that's the output it's producing. What does awk --version tell you? If your awk isn't broken then you must have control characters hidden in your input file.

Comment: The book is a gem, hold on to it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sort -n` at the end, to do a numerical sort.  The default sort would put 10 before 2.

Comment: sort -n is not the answer. If your awk had produced output formatted as you told it to then default, alphabetic sort would have worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your awk is broken or you have control chars in your input.
2. Your printf syntax is wrong (but would still produce correct output)

To get "2" out of the way: printf is a builtin language construct, not a function. When you do this:

```
printf("%s",foo)
```

you are not calling a printf function with 2 arguments, you are invoking the printf builtin with 1 argument which you are constructing from "(" "%s" "," "foo" and ")". The correct syntax is simply:

```
printf "%s",foo
```

but you can stick brackets around any of that and it won't add any value but won't break it either. Any of these would "work" in the same way:

```
printf ("%s"),foo
printf "%s",(foo)
printf ("%s"),(foo)
printf (((((((((("%s",foo))))))))))
```

More importantly, though is point "1" above: you're telling awk to produce output formatted as:

```
"%6.2f ...."
```

which means that the leading digits should be padded with up to 2 leading spaces on the left but your output has no leading spaces on the first line. That is impacting your "sort" but there's more going on here too since given the strings:

```
 2
10
```

it doesn't matter if you do a numeric sort or an alphabetic sort because 2 is numerically less than 10 but space is also numerically less than 1 so the result should be the same either way.

Your posted output, though, is implying that your sort is sorting alphabetically in such a way that "100" is less than " 40" which just is not the way sort works. Even if somehow in your locale  was greater than "1" alphabetically, it wouldn't explain why you get the equivalent of:

```
 2
10
 3
```

in your output, i.e. sometimes it treats space  as less than one and other times as more.

Since your awk is clearly producing bad output there is definitely a problem with either your awk or your input file, so I think it's unlikely that there's also a problem with your sort tool.

Try these commands and post your result if you'd like help debugging your problem:

```
$ awk '{ printf "%6.2f\n" , $2*$3 }' emp.data
  0.00
  0.00
 40.00
100.00
121.00
 76.50

$ awk '{ printf "%6.2f\n" , $2*$3 }' emp.data | sort
  0.00
  0.00
 40.00
 76.50
100.00
121.00
```

I had one other thought - if you messed up the copy/paste of your awk output then maybe it's a locale issue. Try doing this:

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

and then running the command again (without the "-n" on sort).

Comment: Hi Ed, yes after I gave the command `export LC_ALL=C` , I worked without `-n` option to `sort`... But you are probably right that I messed up copy paste. If you look up my output, the numbers are not below one another as in the book's input.... Anyway the reason I am using this book is because it has exercises. I learn new material better by doing exercises. I have that other book you mention but it does not seem to have any exercises.......

Comment: OK, yes it was the messed up copy/paste that threw me into thinking your awk was broken or input was corrupted. You need to figure out the best locale setting for you. Usually C locale provides the fewest surprises but sometimes you need a different setting to get local money formats (e.g. "." vs ","). Like I mentioned, running sort -n is not the answer, fixing your locale setting is.

Comment: wrt the book by Robbins - look at the Sample Programs section. It has examples there of how to implement various UNIX utilities and miscellaneous other examples. Just try to implement those and check your answers with the book.

Comment: Sure Ed, I will look into that

Answer (score 0):

They have assumed sort sorts numerically, your sort appears to default to alphabetically.

Have a look at your sort command line options to see if you can make it numeric.

Comment: John, yes I have to use `-n` option

Comment: No, your problem is not related to sort. Using sort -n just works around the real problem which is that the leading spaces your awk should be producing are not present in sorts input.